# Aws Lambda function not handling all kinesis streams

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, devops, amazon-kinesis

I'm working on a aws lambda function that reads streams from  Kinesis and insert the data in a database.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBb8B.png)

So the first scenario is when im sending only one recorde to kinesis everything goes as excpected and i can see the record in my database

The second scenario is when i send records as batch mode (1000 records), after the execution i check kinesis incaming data metric and i can see the all the 1000 records are arrived, next step is checking the lambda function logs, and there i can see that only some records are executed (2 or 3).
and that is confirmed when i check the database, only 2 or 3 records got inserted.

I can't understand why my lambda is not handling all the records ? the logs also are not telling me much, knowing that i'm handling all the exceptions so no error eccured on the lambda error count metric.

I cant really tell if kinesis is not invoking the lambda on all the records, or if it some kind of configuration that im midding or something else

Here is the methode that sends to kinesis  from the batch :

```
@Override
public void sendChannelRecords(Channel channel) {
    String kinesisStreamName = dataLakeConfig.getKinesisStreamName();
    try {

        byte[] bytes = (conversionToJsonUtils.convertObjectToJsonString(channel) + "\n").getBytes("UTF-8");

        PutRecordRequest putRecordRequest = new PutRecordRequest()
                .withPartitionKey(String.valueOf(random.nextInt()))
                .withStreamName(kinesisStreamName)
                .withData(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes));

        callKinesisAsync(putRecordRequest);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("an error has been occurred during sending Channel to Kinesis : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The handle request of the lambda fucntion :

```
public class RocEventProcessorToTeradata implements RequestHandler<KinesisEvent, Object> {

/**
 * This function write different Collections in Teradata warehouse.
 * Pour cost reasons, we chose to use only a single Kinesis to receive all collections from ROC-API.
 */
private static Logger log = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
private static String LOG_LEVEL = System.getenv("LOGGING_LEVEL");

/**
 * Note that : teradata connexion must be opened & closed inside the the handleRequest method only otherwise connexion remains opened !
 */
@SneakyThrows
public Object handleRequest(KinesisEvent event, Context context) {

    log.setLevel(Level.valueOf(LOG_LEVEL));

    TeradataParams teradataParams = buildTeradataParams();
    List<UserRecord> userRecordsList = RecordDeaggregator.deaggregate(event.getRecords());
    Connection conn = null;
    Channel channel = new ConversionToJava<Channel>().getAsGivenEntity(new String(userRecordsList.get(0).getData().array()), Channel.class);

    boolean isInstanceOfChannel = channel.getEpgid() != null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(teradataParams.getTeradataUrl(), teradataParams.getTeradataUser(), teradataParams.getTeradataPwd());
        if (isInstanceOfChannel) {
            InputFactory.getInputObject(InputType.CHANNEL).apply(conn, userRecordsList, teradataParams);
        } 
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        log.error(" an error has been occurred during connection opening Teradata : {}", e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    } finally {
         //close resources associated to the connection as teradata doesn't allow more than 16 opened resources in the same connection
        try {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("an error has been occurred when closing Teradata connection : {}", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return "";
}

private TeradataParams buildTeradataParams() {
    String teradataUser = getTeradataStoreParam().get(TeradataConnectionParams.USERNAME_PARAM);
    String teradataPwd = getTeradataStoreParam().get(TeradataConnectionParams.PASSWORD_PARAM);
    String teradataUrl = getTeradataStoreParam().get(TeradataConnectionParams.DATABASE_URL);
    String connurl = "jdbc:teradata://" + teradataUrl + "/database=My_DB,tmode=ANSI,charset=UTF8";
    return TeradataParams.builder().teradataUser(teradataUser).teradataPwd(teradataPwd).teradataUrl(connurl).build();
}

private Map<String, String> getTeradataStoreParam() {
    return new ParameterStoreImpl().
            getParameterStore(
                    Lists.newArrayList(TeradataConnectionParams.USERNAME_PARAM,
                            TeradataConnectionParams.PASSWORD_PARAM,
                            TeradataConnectionParams.DATABASE_URL)
            );
}
```

}

```
@Override
public void apply(Connection conn, List<UserRecord> userRecordsList, TeradataParams teradataParams) {
    log.setLevel(Level.valueOf(LOG_LEVEL));

    try {
        Channel channel = new ConversionToJava<Channel>().getAsGivenEntity(new String(userRecordsList.get(0).getData().array()), Channel.class);
        

        ChannelRepository channelRepository = new ChannelRepositoryImpl();
        insertChannelStatement = conn.prepareStatement(ChannelQuery.INSERT_CHANNEL);
        deleteChannelStatement = conn.prepareStatement(ChannelQuery.DELETE_CHANNEL);
        rejectChannelStatement = conn.prepareStatement(ChannelQuery.INSERT_REJET);

        try {
            if (channel.isDeleted()) {
                channelRepository.deleteChannel(channel, deleteChannelStatement);
            } else {
                channelRepository.executeChannel(channel, insertChannelStatement);
            }
            conn.commit();
        } catch (ChannelException e) {
            log.error("an error has been occured during Channel insertion in teradata {}", e.getMessage());
            handleChannelReject(conn, rejectChannelStatement, channel, e);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error(" an error has been occurred during connection opening Teradata Channel: {}", e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            closeStatements(insertChannelStatement, deleteChannelStatement, rejectChannelStatement);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("an error has been occurred when closing Teradata channel connection : {}", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
public class ChannelRepositoryImpl implements ChannelRepository {
    private static Logger log = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
    private static String LOG_LEVEL = System.getenv("LOGGING_LEVEL");
@Override
    public void executeChannel(Channel channel, PreparedStatement statement) {
        log.setLevel(Level.valueOf(LOG_LEVEL));
        final FeedChannelPreparedStatement feedStatement = new FeedChannelPreparedStatement();

        try {
            feedStatement.feedChannelPreparedSatementInsert(statement, channel);
            statement.executeBatch();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Insert Channel Exception : "+ e.getMessage());
            log.error("an error has been occurred during Channel insertion in Teradata : {}", e.getMessage());
            throw new ChannelException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteChannel(Channel channel, PreparedStatement statement) {
        log.setLevel(Level.valueOf(LOG_LEVEL));
        final FeedChannelPreparedStatement feedStatement = new FeedChannelPreparedStatement();

        try {
            System.out.println("Delete Channel : "+ channel.getEpgid());
            feedStatement.feedChannelPreparedSatementDelete(statement, channel);
            statement.executeBatch();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Delete Channel Exception: "+ channel.getEpgid());
            log.error("an error has been occurred during Channel deleting in Teradata : {}", e.getMessage());
            throw new ChannelException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}





public class FeedChannelPreparedStatement extends ChannelPreparedStatement {

void feedChannelPreparedSatementInsert(PreparedStatement statement, Channel channel) throws SQLException {
    List<ProductCodeTable> products = ofNullable(channel.getProducts()).orElse(emptyList());
    if (!products.isEmpty()) {
        for (ProductCodeTable product : products) {
            if (product.getId() != null) {
                addStatementBatch(statement, channel, product.getId());
            }
        }
    } else {
        addStatementBatch(statement, channel, null);
    }
}

void feedChannelPreparedSatementDelete(PreparedStatement statement, Channel channel) throws SQLException {
    addStatementBatchForDelete(statement, channel.getEpgid());
}
```

}

```
public class ChannelPreparedStatement {

private static final int EPGID_ID_INDEX = 1;
private static final int SERVICE_NAME_INDEX = 2;
private static final int PRODUCT_ID_INDEX = 3;
private static final int ID_PROVENANCE_INDEX = 4;
private static final int TMS_CHARGEMENT_INDEX = 5;

void addStatementBatch(PreparedStatement ps, Channel channel, String productId) throws SQLException {

    ps.setObject(EPGID_ID_INDEX, Integer.toString(channel.getEpgid()), Types.VARCHAR);
    ps.setObject(SERVICE_NAME_INDEX, channel.getServiceName(), Types.VARCHAR);
    ps.setObject(PRODUCT_ID_INDEX, productId != null ? productId : "", Types.VARCHAR);
    ps.setInt(ID_PROVENANCE_INDEX, 68);
    ps.setTimestamp(TMS_CHARGEMENT_INDEX, FormatUtil.getTmsChargement());

    ps.addBatch();
}

void addStatementBatchForDelete(PreparedStatement ps, Integer epjId) throws SQLException {
    ps.setObject(EPGID_ID_INDEX, Integer.toString(epjId), Types.VARCHAR);
    ps.addBatch();
}
```

}

Comment: I would set this complex code aside for a moment, write a very simple Lambda function that simply logs each event with its record count and perhaps the list of IDs in the (multiple) records in the batch that triggered the Lambda. Do you get the correct count of records?

Comment: Especially the last part is probably the key: can your lambdas handle batch data? Looking at the code you have `userRecordsList.get(0)` twice which does NOT look like it can handle multiple records well but will instead discard all but the very first incoming record.

Comment: thank you so much, that was helpfull, you are right the error was kind of stupid, i was retreving only the first record by using userRecordsList.get(0).